# Solenoid driver schematic

Tags: circuit-design, mosfet-driver, solenoid-valve

Here is a circuit I'm working on. Its purpose is to accept a PWM signal (PID control) and drive a small [solenoid valve](https://www.parker.com/Literature/Precision%20Fluidics/Miniature%20Proportional%20Valves/062409_HFPRO.pdf) that consumes ~200 mA at 12V. I have some questions I would love to get a second opinion on.

[image: Driver_circuit]

1. The driver IC's [UCC27512](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27511.pdf?ts=1623226229126) reference design shows what I assume to be an AC choke? (L3), they don't specify any max/min value, so I have just chosen 1uH - I would like some feedback on how to choose this value.
2. The [MOSFET](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbf0201nlt1-d.pdf) data sheet specifies that, with a VGS = 10 V, the ID = 300 mA - so I assume the 12V output from the driver IC will be fine.
   Now the driver IC can source and sink a few amps when pulsed and around 300 mA and 600mA continuously.
   Should I keep R16 as a current limiting resistor. Do I even need it?
   I would 100% keep it if I was driving directly from my MCU as the GPIO's can't sink that amount of current.

Comment: This is a boost converter. Every component value matters, specially the inductor VS. frequency. I do think you are going in the wrong way. It would be better to describe what you really want in a new post.

Comment: I think you are right @MarkoBuršič hah... How did I miss that! I think I will look into something like https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002019C.pdf

Comment: What's the goal? You do need a current controller to control the valve, not a simple PWM.

Comment: You can't design a PID regulator unless you take input somewhere. Also, flyback diodes across the valve are absolutely mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control the valve, then you need a current source. I have depicted a sketch for high side driven N-MOSFET that needs a high side gate driver with a charge pump or bootstrap circuit. The current is sensed with a shunt resistor, that needs to be filtered to elimiate the switching pulses. This measured current is than subtracted from setpoint and processed with a PI controller with PWM generator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5S6AO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

The valve current is filtered with RC low pass filter, then a TVS diode is used to protect the opamp buffer that is supplied with same supply as MCU 3.3V or 5V. The MCU samples the current actual value with high speed ADC and then does digital filtering on it, IIR or FIR. The MCU does the PI control and PWM generation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ0PWU.png)</sup>

With one another ADC and analog front end, the flow is measured. The MCU does one additional closed loop control, we call this cascaded loop control. The inner current loop shall execute very fast, meanwhile the outer flow loop has to execute slower, since the system has slower response than current loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Ldal.png)</sup>

EDIT 2:

You could even replace the gate driver and MOSFET with an intelligent automotive high side switch that is capable of PWM control. In my opinion fsw = 5-10kHz is just enough for your application, but it is subject to solenoid inductance/resistance ratio.

The MMBF0201NL is just to small, it is rated to 300mA only. You have to choose more suitable device, something at least 4A continous then it has to be derated due to switching losses and PCB size.

Comment: The feedback is from a flow meter, and I plan on implementing the PI controller in software. I did redo the original schematic and will post an update later :) but yeah a current controlled approach is the way to go.

Comment: @Sorenp My experience from lots of systems like this is that flow meters are very unreliable to use as input. The relation between oil flow and coil inductance is pretty much non-existent. You need to measure the current across the coil instead and use that as input to the PI(D). The design suggested by Marko looks sound, though you can do this in lots of different ways.

Comment: "You could even replace the gate driver and MOSFET with an intelligent automotive high side switch that is capable of PWM control. In my opinion fsw = 5-10kHz is just enough for your application, but it is subject to solenoid inductance/resistance ratio." That's what I've used in similar projects, though they are usually fairly slow. It's good to regulate with as fast PWM as possible to get closer to an analog signal rather than a pulse train. Otherwise you need to sync your current sampling so that always happens at a certain point in the duty cycle. Which in turn adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: @Lundin I agree with you. But if the inductance is enough high, the re-circulation current will flow through D1 and the shunt resistor as well, you get a triangle wave of 10kHz. This is then passed through anti-alias filter, in my example it has near 700Hz cut-off, then with one additional FIR filter it would make the need of a sync ADC timing less important. The valve is fairly slow system, it doesn't need a precise time current measurement as motor control would need.

Comment: @Lundin Always appreciate your inputs, thanks :) - yes I have my eyes on DRV110.

MarkoBuršič Yeah I was thinking about cascading the control systems, one to regulate the current draw and one to regulate based on the feedback from the flow meter. Some guy called Ohm kept messing with me when trying to regulate the current without touching on the voltage.

Comment: @Sorenp That's the whole problem, the resistance will vary a lot in these kind of systems, depending on what coil that's used, temperature fluctuations, length of cables and so on. The supply voltage of the valve isn't typically that reliable either and of course there's also voltage drops with higher currents over cables. So we need to measure and regulate _current_.

Comment: @Lundin Would you expect me to toggle the EN pin on a device like DRV110 based on the flow meter? I don't see any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Sorenp I don't know what DRV110 is, but as Marko advised you can use an intelligent high side (or low side) driver, basically a MOSFET with lots of protection and internal voltage regulator. And then you measure the current over a high precision low ohm resistor like Rsense in this schematic. There's specialized comparators designed for that very purpose.

Comment: @Sorenp Here's a good place to start: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-low-side-high-side-switches/. Much as I dislike Infineon, they are completely dominant in this sector and their products are very good (you just can't buy their parts, they are an extremely unreliable vendor with constant production problems).

Comment: @Lundin Those smart switches capable of PWM were made from IOR that Infineon aquired and they are obsolete.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič It depends on what frequency you need. Some of the newer PROFET drivers can switch at least up to one MHz somewhere. I don't remember the exact spec.

Comment: @Sorenp You can use DRV104,DRV10x,..you have to decide if you need a High side driver, for better protection and easy measurement, or you go with low side drive. Then you have to decide or use a complete solution like DRV10x (IMO not so good approach) or you will write the code for PWM in the MCU and you gain full control.

Comment: @Lundin BTF 50060-1TEA is the only one.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič DRV104 looks exactly like something I need ! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the assistance, I will continue my work and provide an update to the post at a later stage.